# I need to figure out multiple UIActionsSheets?

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I am trying to create multiple UIActions sheets with my view. I have read a few questions on here and browsed the internet, but nothing seems to get me a valid answer.

I have tried the "switch and case" method that looks like this....

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
switch (actionSheet.tag) {
    case 10:

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
```

and I have tried this method too...

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet1;
UIActionSheet *actionSheet2;
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:        (NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(actionSheet==actionSheet1)
{
```

The action sheet options work as individuals, so I know that the links and code is right, but I can't seem to get them both to work at the same time.

Let me know if I need to post more code.

Cheers Jeff

---

More Info:

```
-(IBAction)Action01:(id)sender {
UIActionSheet *actionSheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Choose a Website:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"Google Maps",nil];
actionSheet1.tag = 10;
[actionSheet1 showInView:self.view];
```

}

and the second one is set up with tag = 11.O have also linked the buttons in Interface Builder with the same tag number.

In my heads file, I have defined my properties and IB Actions as well. Everything is done properly as it works if i use only one or the other of the action sheets and comment the rest out.

Here are the links to the files if it makes them easier:
[Header file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1246132/Stackoverflow/MultipleActionAndAlertsViewController.h) 
[Implementation file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1246132/Stackoverflow/MultipleActionAndAlertsViewController.m)

Cheers Jeff

Comment: Much better. ^_^ Now, can you please add some more details as to where and how you set up your actions sheets? Are you setting those tags?

Comment: I have just updated my post - hope the information is helpful.

Comment: @jwk82 Are you trying to show two action sheets at once or have one view controller be the delegate for two action sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in your updated post that you have set the tags in Interface Builder *and* in code. This is likely causing a conflict. You don't want those IB buttons to have the same tags as the action sheet, or strange thing will happen.

Change the tags in Interface Builder and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope Sorry that did not fix it. I set both tags to zero so the buttons in IB do not relate to the code.